# Can WP7 do location arrive/depart based reminders?

Tags: alarms, reminders

I'm not at all familiar with iPhone but it appears from this screenshot on the Apple Tips & Tricks page that it can do reminders based on arriving/departing from certain known locations:
[image]

Ignoring the fact that for Apple this a Siri feature, the basic concept of reminders being triggered by geography (arriving/departing) is useful sounding. Is this something that WP7 can do built in or with an app?

Again, I'm not interested in the Siri/voice element, managing it via keyboard entry would be totally fine.

Comment: I remember seeing a website or something like that that would let you send yourself GPS alerts based on where your phone was. But I can't find it now.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a standard built in one, like Siri, but there are third party apps that do something similar, such as [this one](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/location-alarm/eb603228-001b-4b8e-9dd1-825109807cd8) (that I'm not affiliated with, nor have used in anger)